newcommand with node into a tikzpicture-environment and into a TikZ-matrix
Why does this not work in common?
\newcommand{\test}[2][]{
\node[draw, #1] {#2};
}

Only if I say
\newcommand{\test}[2][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw, #1] {#2};
\end{tikzpicture}
}

it works sometimes - but everytime a complete tikzpicture...?
Hint: I want so set a more complex command (contains foreach) several times into a TikZ-matrix, so the following MWE contains a TikZ-matrix.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\test}[2][]{
\node[draw, #1] {#2};
}

\test{aaa} % Does not work! ==================

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
a & b \\
\test{aaa} & \test[red]{bbb} \\
% Does not work! ==================
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


The code did not work with \newcommand because then the command is not expandable, as illustrated in the example below: \testA is defined with \newcommand but can not be used in \edef. Whereas \testC is defined with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand and \testC can be used in \edef.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\newcommand{\testA}[2][]{A}
\def\testB{\testA{B}}%works with \def but not with \edef
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\testC{O{}m}{C}
\edef\testD{\testC{D}}%works with \def and \edef
\begin{document}
\testB ; \testD
\end{document}


If the command \test is defined with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand then \test can be used inside the \matrix.
\documentclass[border=6pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\test{O{}m}{\node[draw, #1] {#2};}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes, nodes in empty cells]{
a & b \\
\test{aaa} & \test[red]{bbb} \\
%Does work
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Ahhh..... TYVM!
